# i have installed ubuntu 14.04 but unable to update or install any third party software

Tags: 14.04

i have installed ubuntu 14.04 but unable to update or install any third party software.
Even i am trying to install video codec for video file but not working.

Please see below:

```
root@samiul-Inspiron-N5010:/home/samiul# sudo apt-get install libavcodec- extra-53   libavcodec53 ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libavcodec-extra-53
E: Unable to locate package libavcodec53
E: Unable to locate package ffmpeg
```

I am getting this error

Comment: I guess all you need is a `sudo apt update` if you just installed Ubuntu. Otherwise, you may want to make sure to select an appropriate server and repository sources in Softwares and Updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just installed the System run `sudo apt-get update` first.
In 14.04 [libav](http://libav.org/) is shipped instead of ffmpeg.
If you want to use ffmpeg download it [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you. it automatically asked for update and i did it.

Answer (score 1):

Thread is a little old, but I was looking for this myself.

libavcodec53 and libavcodec-extra-53 are not supported on 14.04.  You need to run `sudo apt-get install libav-tools` for the latest supported version.